# How to convert time in seconds to 00:00:00 format in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example, if times is given as 1.05 seconds, we need to convert it as 00:01:05.

How can we achieve this in Flutter?

Also, if a time is given as duration in milliseconds, how do we convert it to the 00:00:00 format?

Comment: I have *never* seen `:` delimit seconds from milliseconds.  That would be very confusing.  "00:01:05" usually would be interpreted to mean 1 minute, 5 seconds (or possibly 1 hour, 5 minutes).  I strongly recommend against using that format due to the ambiguity.

Comment: There was a requirement for using this format for showing time for video during playing. Can you suggest a better format for showing the time.

Comment: I would represent 1.05 seconds either as "00:00:01.050" or as "1.05s".  As another example, I would represent 2 minutes, 59.1 seconds as "00:02:59.100" or as "2m59.1s".

Answer (score 0):

You just need some simple integer maths to separate the duration into the units you want and some string formatting to make sure that single-digit numbers get leading zeros.

```
String formatForVideo(Duration d) {
  final millis = d.inMilliseconds;
  if (millis >= 3600000) {
    throw FormatException('too big to format');
  }
  final minutes = _pad2(d.inMinutes);
  final seconds = _pad2(d.inSeconds % 60);
  final cents = _pad2((millis % 1000) ~/ 10);

  return '$minutes:$seconds.$cents';
}

String _pad2(int i) => i.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
```

Which gives expected results:

```
print(formatForVideo(Duration(minutes: 0, seconds: 1, milliseconds: 50))); // 00:01.05
print(formatForVideo(Duration(minutes: 9, seconds: 51, milliseconds: 50))); // 09:51.05
print(formatForVideo(Duration(minutes:60))); // exception
```

Answer (score -1):

> The output of this definition => 00:00:00

```
DateTime time = DateTime(1990, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

> Then when you want to add a period to this time

```
time.add(const Duration(seconds: 100,milliseconds:200))
```

> and for output =>

```
String timeString = DateFormat.Hms().format(time);

print(timeString);
```

Result =>>    00:01:40